# Postgresql function If condition then run query else stop

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, postgresql

I need some help with the following postgres functionality

I have the following table with the columns:

```
array, array_length
```

I initially have a few arrays in and then I run a query(actually a set of 3 queries) that selects the arrays, appends them, and then inserts the appended arrays into the table.

I need to loop this insert query until one of the arrays (`select max(array_length) from table`) reaches a predefined size, say length 50.

I basically need to write something like

```
begin 
for (select max(array_length) from table)<50
loop 
(drop table if exists super_item_temp;
ALTER TABLE super_item
    RENAME TO super_item_temp;

create table super_item as 
select distinct * from super_item_temp;

insert into super_item 
select ...calculations... from super_item)
end
```

but I cannot find the right syntax to write this

I looked at the manual at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html
but I could not find anything helpful.

Any hints or links pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated!
Thank you.

Edit: I tried

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIOn function_name() RETURNS int4 AS '
DECLARE r RECORD;

BEGIN
    WHILE (select max(array_length) from super_item)<50

```
loop
drop table if exists super_item_temp;
    ALTER TABLE super_item
        RENAME TO super_item_temp;

    create table super_item as 
    select distinct * from super_item_temp;


    insert into super_item 
    select old_array, 
    array_sort_unique( array_agg(added_item) || a.old_array) as new_array, 
    array_length(array_sort_unique( array_agg(added_item) || a.old_array),1)

    from (
            select 
    a.new_array as old_array,

    case when string_to_array(b.item2::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array and string_to_array(b.item1::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array then null
     when string_to_array(b.item2::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array then b.item1 else b.item2 end  as added_item

    from

    super_item a 
    left join pairs b 

    on  string_to_array(b.item1::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array or  string_to_array(b.item2::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array /**any item from pair is in array**/
    where 1=1

    group by a.new_array, 2

    having sum(b.count)>10
    and sum(b.offset)<=0 
    and 
    case 
    when string_to_array(b.item2::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array and string_to_array(b.item1::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array then null
    when string_to_array(b.item2::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array then b.item1 else b.item2 end is not null
    /**new item is not null**/
    order by 2 desc
    )a
    group by 1;
END LOOP;
```

return 1;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT function_name() as output;

now I am getting an error 'unknown column' for a function argument which should be a quoted separator.

> error:  column „,“ existiert nicht LINE 18:   on 
>   string_to_array(b.item1::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_ar...

Comment: use `while` instead of `for` --> `WHILE (select max(array_length) from table)<50 LOOP .....`

Comment: i tried, i am just not sure what to put for arguments and so on. I don't care about the arguments or what it returns, i just need it to run the loop when called. I added to the post.

Comment: Please post the table definition - `CREATE TABLE super_item ....` statement.

Comment: CREATE TABLE super_item
(
  old_array integer[],
  new_array integer[],
  array_length integer
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

Comment: There is no 'END LOOP' statement in the code - the right syntax is `WHILE condition LOOP statements END LOOP`.

Comment: Edited, now I get a different error, where it thinks a quoted string is a column.

Comment: Is that big SELECT query works ? Have you tried it in sql editor (not inside the function) ? I guess that this SELECT statement is wrong, try it in editor and correct errors first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, on my PC it compiles fine (however I don't know whether it works as expected).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION append_super_item ()
RETURNS integer AS $length$
declare
    length integer;
BEGIN
  WHILE (select max(array_length) from super_item)<50
    LOOP
       drop table if exists super_item_temp;
       ALTER TABLE super_item
            RENAME TO super_item_temp;
       Create table super_item as 
         select distinct * from super_item_temp;
       insert into super_item 
    select old_array, 
    array_sort_unique( array_agg(added_item) || a.old_array) as new_array, 
    array_length(array_sort_unique( array_agg(added_item) || a.old_array),1)

    from (
            select 
    a.new_array as old_array,

    case when string_to_array(b.item2::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array and string_to_array(b.item1::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array then null
     when string_to_array(b.item2::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array then b.item1 else b.item2 end  as added_item

    from

    super_item a 
    left join pairs b 

    on  string_to_array(b.item1::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array or  string_to_array(b.item2::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array /**any item from pair is in array**/
    where 1=1

    group by a.new_array, 2

    having sum(b.count)>10
    and sum(b.offset)<=0 
    and 
    case 
    when string_to_array(b.item2::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array and string_to_array(b.item1::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array then null
    when string_to_array(b.item2::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_array then b.item1 else b.item2 end is not null
    /**new item is not null**/
    order by 2 desc
    )a
    group by 1;
    end loop;
end $length$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: it runs fine, creates the function, however when I call it it gives me the error FEHLER:  Spalte „,“ existiert nicht
LINE 18:     on  string_to_array(b.item1::text, ",")::int[] <@ a.new_...

Comment: it is basically interpreting a quoted string as a column. Query runs fine outside of the function